# Reg Ex - PHP - grep line without { at the end of line

Tags: php, regex

ex: ^[^# | / | }] , which grep only rows without these character at the begining , but I wanna grep all lines without line "typedef struct SymbolTable {" 
Thanks for answers.

My output now looks like this:

```
typedef  int NUMBER;
typedef struct SymbolTable {
SymbolTable* symbol_table_new();
void symbol_table_go_local(SymbolTable* table);
bool symbol_table_is_local(SymbolTable* table);
```

But I need just:

```
typedef  int NUMBER;
SymbolTable* symbol_table_new();
void symbol_table_go_local(SymbolTable* table);
bool symbol_table_is_local(SymbolTable* table);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your input file has Windows line endings (CRLF) you will need to add an `\r` to your `explode` call, i.e. replace your `explode("\n", $input_lines)` with `explode("\r\n", $input_lines)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use the end of line anchor

```
^[^#|/}].*[^{]$
```

Comment: Iam using :
preg_grep("/^[^#|\/}].*[^{]$/", explode("\n", $input_lines));
But it didnt work :/ Iam really desperate of it.

Comment: @PeťoHnat what is `$input_lines`?